# Save model to database

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, asp.net-mvc

I recently asked a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/348404/195792) on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) and I had a comment:

> The updated version has some issues which are out of topic here. You may consider posting it at codereview.stackexchange.com to get some suggestions for improvements.

The code I had asked in that site:

```
public class GroupBillingPayment
{
    public void Save(IGroupBillingPayment model)
    {
        if (model == null || UserInfo.UserID == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("GroupBillingPayment object or Current User Id is NULL , Please Contact Administrator.");
        }
        Data.GroupBillingPayment groupBillingPayment = RepositoryManager.GroupBillingPaymentRepository.GetById(model.GroupBillingPaymentID);
        Mapper.Map(model, groupBillingPayment);
        ServiceManager.GroupBilling.IsBillAlreadyCancelled(groupBillingPayment.GroupBillingID, THROW_ERROR);
        groupBillingPayment.UpdatedBy = UserInfo.UserID;
        groupBillingPayment.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;        
        RepositoryManager.GroupBillingPaymentRepository.Update(groupBillingPayment, false);
        UpdateGroupBilling(groupBillingPayment.GroupBillingPaymentID, groupBillingPayment.GroupBillingID)
    }
}
```

Could anyone please highlight the issues in this method?

A bit more details about the above method:

`ServiceManager` and `RepositoryManager` are private properties, which have been injected into this class via constructor using Autofac.

The `Service`/`Repository` managers contain the reference to the classes in that particular layer. Hence `ServiceManager` can access the service `GroupBilling` which is in service layer and `RepositoryManager` can access `GroupBillingPaymentRepository`.

The classes in service and repository layers are resolved using Autofac and so is `UserInfo`.

[Parameters] are the necessary parameters required for that method to run. In this case, it is `groupBillingPayment.GroupBillingPaymentID` and `groupBillingPayment.GroupBillingID` (have updated the code to reflect this).

Comment: Welcome to CR! I'd suggest you give us a bit more context, e.g. where's `Mapper` coming from? Is `RepositoryManager` a `static` class? With `GroupBillingPaymentRepository` being a *nested* `static` class exposing a `static` `Update` method? Same with `ServiceManager.GroupBilling`, and what's `[Parameters]`? Where's `UserInfo` coming from? The more context you give reviewers, the better we can help you, without making guesses and assumptions.

Comment: Hope I have provided the necessary details

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's *better* indeed, but I would have just provided the class' code exactly as you have it in the IDE; it's easier to picture `UserInfo` being a property when it shows up in the code block as such - and as a bonus if there's an issue with the definition or implementation of that property then reviewers can point it out, too! Note that edits are always better off seamless; people that want to see the edit history can always see it by clicking the "edited x mins ago" timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> if (model == null || UserInfo.UserID == 0)
> {
>   throw new Exception("GroupBillingPayment object or Current User Id is NULL , Please Contact Administrator.");
> }
> ```

You should split this into two `if`s and two different exceptions.

The first one should only check the parameter passed and throw the `ArgumentNullException` because we don't throw the `Exception` directly but some more specific ones that convey more information.

The other one should be the `InvalidOperationException` which means that the object is in an invalid state which would be when the `UserInfo.UserID` is `0`.

---

> ```
>  ServiceManager.GroupBilling.IsBillAlreadyCancelled(
>        groupBillingPayment.GroupBillingID,
>        THROW_ERROR);
> ```

If the second parameter does what I think it does, this is, indicates whether the method should throw an exception or not then this is a very bad idea. If you need a method that does not throw then you should create another one by following the *try-something* pattern.

```
  if(ServiceManager.GroupBilling.TryGetBillAlreadyCancelled(
       groupBillingPayment.GroupBillingID,
       out bool canceled))
  {
      ...
  }
```